# Select elements from a list depending on condition

Tags: list-manipulation

Assume I have:

```
list = {{Mean[{}], 668}, {1, 2}, {Mean[{}], 2}, {7, 8}}
```

and I want to select only pairs, where the first element is not equal to `Mean[{}]`.

Then I find two solutions, which I not really understand:

```
Select[list, #[[1]] > 0 &]

{{1, 2}, {7, 8}}

Select[list, Length[#[[1]]] == 0 &]

{{1, 2}, {7, 8}}
```

Can you explain me why these examples produce the correct result?

Which solution would you propose?

Comment: The first element of your pairs is either a positive integer, obviously with length 0,  or a non atomic expression, with positive length. Therefore both solutions work. An alternative is  `Cases[list, {_Integer, _}]`.

Comment: @Fred Simons: I like your solution more ...

Comment: also `DeleteCases[list, {_Mean, _}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run

```
Mean[{}]>0
```

you will find that this does not return True. When you run the Select command it returns those elements for which the condition is True. While Mean[{}]>0 doesn't return False, nor does it return True.

For the second one, Length[Mean[{}]] evaluates to 1, and so Length[Mean[{}]]==0 is false. If you want to do this more explicitly you can write:

```
Select[list, #[[1]] =!= Mean[{}] &]
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `=!=`?

Comment: It returns true unless the two expressions are identical. It is the negation of ===

Comment: @lio, a tip for the future: everytime you encounter an unfamiliar symbol in *Mathematica*, highlight it in a notebook, and press F1.